# Dice loss working only when probs are squared at denominator

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, image-segmentation, loss-function

I'm experiencing an interesting and frustrating issue with the Dice loss used in image segmentation with Unet.

I have to segment images in two classes: background and region of interest. The region of interest is typically 4% of the pixels of the whole image. Images are about 1600x1600 pixels.
I found the Dice loss working much better than Cross Entropy.
However, if I use the standard Dice loss formula my Unet does not provide a correct output, i.e. all the pixels are predicted as background.

With standard Dice loss I mean:

[image]

where x_{c,i} is the probability predicted by Unet for pixel i and for channel c, and y_{c,i} is the corresponding ground-truth label.
The modified version I use is:

[image]

Note the squared x at the denominator.

For some reason the latter one makes the net to produce a correct output, although the loss converges to ~0.5.

I do not understand why the latter works and the former doesn't. The latter works even if I use the power of three at the denominator.

Here below my implementation:

```
def make_one_hot(labels, classes):
    one_hot = torch.FloatTensor(labels.size()[0], classes, labels.size()[2], labels.size()[3]).zero_().to(labels.device)
    target = one_hot.scatter_(1, labels.data, 1)
    return target


class DiceLoss(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(DiceLoss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, output, target):

        target = make_one_hot(target.unsqueeze(dim=1), classes=output.size()[1])
        output = F.softmax(output, dim=1)

        numerator = (output * target).sum(dim=(2, 3))
        denominator = output.pow(2).sum(dim=(2, 3)) + target.sum(dim=(2, 3))

        iou = numerator / denominator

        return 1 - iou.mean()
```

Comment: Hi! I do not have an answer. Just wanted to let you know that I experienced the same phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, this is valuable information!

Answer (score 0):

Milletari et al. already explain this when they propose this in [the paper of V-Net](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04797.pdf). They suggest that the ROI may only occupy a very small region of the whole scan, which is likely to be biased towards the background. Since you say your ROI is about 4% of the whole image, maybe you're facing a similar issue.

[image]

Comment: that's not an explanation about why they are squaring the denominator, but instead it's an explanation about why they are using the dice loss, which indeed helps in situations where the majority of pixels belong to the background class. I have no idea why they are squaring the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.02855.pdf), the authors say "Milletari et al. (2016) proposed to change the denominator to the square form for faster convergence..." They are referencing the [V-Net paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04797.pdf), which to my knowledge does not mention why they squared the terms in the denominator. However, I think that the formula used in that paper is only based on the Dice coefficient. They define it for binary segmentation volumes, so squaring does not change the values. But the same cannot be true if you are using softmax probabilities.

It makes sense though that squaring the terms could create a smoother loss landscape and therefore, faster convergence. For what it is worth, I have used the non-squared version of dice loss (*1 - DSC*) with good results. They are still optimizing the same thing (i.e. region overlap). However, if you are reporting the DSC as a performance metric, I would use the non-squared version.